# Duda consulta SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

**A partir de estas dos tablas:**

```
CREATE TABLE Socio(
  cod_socio NUMBER CONSTRAINT cd_pk PRIMARY KEY,   
  NIF VARCHAR2(9) CONSTRAINT nif_uni UNIQUE,
  nombre VARCHAR2(30) CONSTRAINT nom_nnull NOT NULL
); 

CREATE TABLE Libro(
  cod_libro VARCHAR2(6) CONSTRAINT lib_pk PRIMARY KEY,
  editorial VARCHAR2(30) CONSTRAINT edit_nnull NOT NULL,
  edicion VARCHAR2(30) CONSTRAINT edic_nnull NOT NULL,
  precio FLOAT CONSTRAINT prec_nnull NOT NULL,
  cod_socio NUMBER,
  CONSTRAINT cods_fk FOREIGN KEY (cod_socio) REFERENCES Socio (cod_socio)
);
```

Debo hacer una consulta en la cual aparezca el nombre de socio y el número de libros que tiene este socio. He hecho esto y no consigo ver el fallo:

```
SELECT nombre, COUNT(cod_libro) AS "Número de libros" 
FROM Libro
NATURAL JOIN Socio 
GROUP BY cod_socio;
```

¿Alguien podría echarme una mano?

Comment: ¿Qué gestor de bases de datos usas?

Comment: Oracle sql developer

Comment: La solución va como respuesta amigo, quitalo de tu pregunta y publicalo debajo por favor

Answer (score 1):

Lo que ocupas en estos casos es:

- Usar `INNER JOIN` pues así solo obtendremos los socios que si tienen libros rtegistrados, es decir que su llave primaria aparece al menos 1 vez como llave foránea en la tabla libros
- Tu agrupamiento debe considerar a todas las columnas del `SELECT` menos aquellas que resultan del cálculo por ejemplo del conteo
- Además para saber cuantos libros tiene cada socio la columna que debes contabilizar es **cod_socio** y no la de libro, pues la primera que menciono esta vinculada con cada libro registrado a una persona

> Me disculpo me hacía falta la igualación de la sentencia ON (cosa que no habia notado)

Así debería quedar

```
SELECT cod_libro, nombre, COUNT(cod_socio) AS "Número de libros" 
FROM Libro
INNER JOIN Socio ON tabla1.clavePrimaria = tabla2.claveForanea
GROUP BY cod_libro, nombre;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda y por responder. Aunque entiendo la solución y el concepto, la he probado en el gestor y da este error sobre el GROUP BY: 00905 missing keyword

Comment: permiteme modificar y revisa nuevamente

Comment: De esa forma sigue dando el mismo error. He añadido (entre el INNER JOIN y el GROUP BY): ON (libro.cod_socio = socio.cod_socio) y funciona. Aunque si un socio tiene 2 libros o más, en tabla muestra dos entradas del mismo socio con 1 libro en cada entrada

Comment: Por favor en tu pregunta edita y agrega algunos datos de muestra para poder replicar tu ejercicio y revisar mas a detalle

Comment: Lo siento. Lo haré

Answer (score 1):

Ya ha quedado resuelta la duda:

**SOLUCIÓN**

```
SELECT nombre, COUNT(Libro.cod_socio) AS "Número de Libros" 
FROM Libro 
INNER JOIN Socio 
ON (Libro.cod_socio = Socio.cod_socio) 
GROUP BY Socio.cod_socio,nombre;
```

Pd: Espero que ayude en futuras dudas de otros usuarios.

Muchas gracias por la ayuda prestada y un saludo

Comment: +1 no olvides marcarla como aceptada. Saludos

Comment: En que se diferencia esta respuesta de la que te dieron originalmente?

Comment: Simplemente se editaron al mismo tiempo. Aunque analizando la respuesta de aprendiz el en el group by pone cod_libro y yo cod_socio (a mi me funciono con la que yo puse)